# Inject a service while importing a module

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I would like to import a servie, while importing a module. PFB the sample code

```
 @Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [configuration],
      isGlobal: true,
      ignoreEnvFile: true
    }),    
    CacheModule.register({
      store:redisStore,
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 6379,
      ttl:300
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here, in CacheModule, I want to use configService so that all the attributes can be from config, is this possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution, actually, what I requested was not possible, however nestjs has already provided a way to inject dependency.

```
CacheModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    ttl: configService.get('CACHE_TTL'),
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap up configService in configModule. Like

```
@Module({
  controllers: [ConfigController],
  providers: [ConfigService],
  exports: [ConfigService ]
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

You have to export the ConfigService in the module that provides it.

and then import the exporting module in the module that uses the service:

```
@Module({
  controllers: [CacheController],
  providers: [CacheService],
  imports: [**ConfigModule**]
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
export class CacheModule {}
```

Do not add the same provider to multiple modules. Export the provider, import the module.

Comment: Thanks, but CacheModule.register is a funciton already defined in @nestjs/common
is there any way I can use configService in the dynamic module defined already.